# Retrieving in wxWidgets a web page which is available after logging in

Tags: wxwidgets

Would someone please post here an example of downloading in wxWidgets application a web page which is available after logging in?

I tried to use wxCurl for this purpose, but no success, a buffer is not filled with content of a page. :-(

```
char Buffer[30000];
wxCurlHTTP http(wxT("http://taras.te.ua/index.php"), wxT("test"), wxT("test"));
http.UseCookies(true);
http.Post(Buffer, 30000);
wxString Content = wxString(Buffer, wxConvUTF8);
wxMessageBox(Content);
```

Comment: How is the login processed? Simple HTTP authentication or user/password form (POST)?